# If no featured image is set, default.png from core is shown

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm encountering a weird issue when getting featured image urls with `wp_get_attachment_image_src`.  If no featured image has been set, this should return null.  However, in this case its returning `wp-includes/images/crystal/default.png`.

The code I'm using to get the URL is:

```
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'full', true);
$thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0]
```

This is happening in WordPress 4.1.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all plugins and using a default theme?

Comment: Yes. It happens in Twenty Fourteen with all plugins disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's the `wp_get_attachment_image_scr` function:

```
function wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $size='thumbnail', $icon = false) {

    // get a thumbnail or intermediate image if there is one
    if ( $image = image_downsize($attachment_id, $size) )
        return $image;

    $src = false;

    if ( $icon && $src = wp_mime_type_icon($attachment_id) ) {
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post.php */
        $icon_dir = apply_filters( 'icon_dir', ABSPATH . WPINC . '/images/media' );
        $src_file = $icon_dir . '/' . wp_basename($src);
        @list($width, $height) = getimagesize($src_file);
    }
    if ( $src && $width && $height )
        return array( $src, $width, $height );
    return false;
}
```

as u can see if 3-rd param is true then it looks in icons dir for that image ( and i assume `wp_mime_type_icon` returns `default.png` and some of your plugins `add_filter` to `icon_dir` to be `wp-includes/images/crystal`

Just remove 3-rd parameter in your example:
`$thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'full');`
and it should return `false` if no image or image url

Comment: Ah Thanks!  It was right in front of my face in the Codex as well.